How to ensure type narrowing works on returned value
Image I have a function that returns an object. I did type narrowing on that object within the function and want the type narrowing be available for the caller. But for some reason this does not work. Did I miss something?
type X = { prop: undefined | string };
function f(x: X) {
    if (typeof x.prop === 'undefined') throw new TypeError();  // narrow "prop" to not-undefined
    x.prop.charAt(0);                   // <- no error here as type narrowing worked
    return { x };
}
f({ prop: undefined }).x.prop.charAt(0);   // <- here I get the error that "prop" is possibly undefined, 
                                        // although f() narrowed it to not-undefined


You're running into ms/TS#42384. Type guards on properties don't generally narrow the parent object. If you want that you'll have to either reassemble the object, or implement ms/TS#42384 manually as a custom type guard function. Both approaches are shown in this playground link. If that fully answers your question I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

Great answer! If you copy that as answer I'll vote for it...

I was going to write one but I found this one which is essentially the same in terms of my answer.
